# How to close one of two minimised ovelapping laucher icons?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a problem I have to close a window that is minimized without maximize it and it's icon is overlapping with another one on the launcher so I can't close one without closing both,the other being the main app.Is there some work-around that can help me with this,maybe some setting that can prevent icons on the launcher from overlapping?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close minimized window without maximizing, right click on the icon of the app and select **Quit** button.

If you have a lot apps you can press **Ctrl+Super+D** to minimize them all.

Comment: Yeah but I have several icons overlapped and I want to close a specific one,which should stay minimized when closed to produce some effect.

Comment: Maybe consider trying Alt+Tab. You can choose which to close from the appeared windows.